# How to remove lesstif and install Open Motif?

Tags: installation, uninstall, libraries, shared-library, motif

We are having some problems with the LKB installation on Ubuntu http://moin.delph-in.net/LkbFaq and the solution posted on the FAQ site says: 
"The LKB interaction window appears but none of the menus work. This happens when you have lesstif installed. You will have to remove/relocate the lesstif libraries and install Open Motif."

How do i remove lesstif libraries and then install Open Motif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo apt-get remove lesstif

sudo apt-get install openmotif